# How to generate Unreal Visual Studio solution files into specific folders

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I am on Windows 10 and Unreal 4.15.

When I right click a Unreal project to generate Visual Studio solution files, there isn't any option to change the output directory, and it always goes to the same folder as the project file, which means the source files and the build files are mixed together.

For traditional C++ projects where the build files are generated by CMake, we can do something like:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -A x64 ..
msbuild test.sln
```

The build files and source files are separated. Is it possible to do this kind of good practice for Unreal projects?

Below is the command line I am currently using to generate the build files for Unreal:

```
UnrealBuildTool.exe -projectfiles -project="%WORKSPACE%/projectname/projectname.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not mixed together completely. As far as I know, Unreal Engine projects requires an exactly defined folder structure ([Unreal Engine documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/DirectoryStructure/#gameprojectdirectories)).

So your **C++ source code** is in folder *Source*, but **generated** files for Visual Studio or equivalent tool are in folder *Intermediate*. So these files are usually not versioned by Git or other versioning tools. (GitHub has a nice predefined .gitignore file for Unreal Engine [GitHub Unreal Engine .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/UnrealEngine.gitignore)).

In conclusion - no, **it is not possible** and in my opinion it would be also contraproductive - currently it works perfectly even for big projects with multiple gameplay modules (they are actually DLL files [Gameplay Modules documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Modules/Gameplay/)).

Comment: I also figured out using `.gitignore` as the temporary solution, not ideal for me but works. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3667089 You are welcome. May ask you: why you want to have Intermediate folder somwere else? I can imagine only one reason for that - build build speed on SSD versus large Content forder. This case is solveable with directory links (see mklink command) and having content on classic drive and Intermediate on SSD.

Comment: [This](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/04/16/why-you-should-consider-using-separate-build-directories/) sums it up pretty well, easy clean, possibility of different build setups, no need to babysit generated files

Comment: @user3667089 Wow, this approach does make sense. Maybe you should ask on https://answers.unrealengine.com/index.html ,it is UE forum and they could give you definite answer (since staff there is directly in contact with UE developers) and also, they could give you some hints, how to achieve this in UE environment if possible (since thanks to Unreal Build Tool and properietary reflection system, building is not as simple as classic C++ app)

Comment: It is actually already asked [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?138765-How-to-generate-Unreal-visual-studio-solution-files-into-specific-folders), unfortunately it seems like there is no obvious way to alternate the folder structure